# CasperJS form fill sometimes stays on the current page

Tags: casperjs, fill

I have a simple casperjs test to submit a search form on my homepage. Then I assert that the title on the landing page is correct.

Works fine on my computer (OSX 10.9.2) but on my colleague's laptops (a Win 7 and Win 8), the test fails randomly because casper "thinks" it is still on the search page.

```
casper.test.begin('Search', function(test) {

  casper.start("http://localhost:8080/site", function() {
    this.fill(searchForm, { query: goodQuery }, true);
  });

  casper.then(function() {
    // sometimes fails, says it's "My Project" main title
    test.assertTitle('Search Result', 'Search result title is ok');
  });
}
```

Introducing a `casper.waitFor(3000)` before checking the page title does not change the outcome. I've also tried to replace the `then` step by a `waitForUrl`, but it fails after 5 secs, saying it is still on the current page.

Plenty of other tests work fine on all computers but it's the only one with form submition.

Any hints on how to solve or properly work around this? I'd rather not simulate a click on the submit button (more coupling to the form internals) if possible (but it would be okay I guess).

Thanks

```
$ casperjs --version
1.1.0-beta3
$ phantomjs --version
1.9.7
```

**EDIT:** submitting the form and `waitForUrl`did not help. I found out that the test actually runs fine on its own, even on the Windows 7 machine. But when I run two tests:

- 01 search.js  (the one described above)
- 02 menu.js    (a simple one, merely containing assertExists)

'search.js' fails most of the time... and sometimes 'menu.js' fails instead! I suspect some mishandled concurrent access, although it consistently works on OSX. I must be doing something wrong. Both tests have the same structure:

```
casper.test.begin('Some test', function(test) {

    casper.start(someUrl, function() {
        // some test
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
casper.test.begin('Search', function(test) {

     casper.start("http://localhost:8080/site", function() {
        this.fill(searchForm, { 
            query: goodQuery 
        },false);
        this.click("your selector for submit button");
      });

     casper.then(function() {//you should use waitForUrl/Selector/Text() instead
        // sometimes fails, says it's "My Project" main title
        test.assertTitle('Search Result', 'Search result title is ok');
      });

    casper.run(function() {
        this.test.comment('------ Tests over ----\n');
        test.done();
    });
});
```

It's better to submit the form by clicking. Sometimes (often) it doesn't pass putting the fill arg at true. Just put the correct selector for the submit button.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense but it didn't fix it. Please see additional info under 'EDIT' in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for an item to appear on the following page. I would change your code to the following:

```
casper.test.begin('Search', function(test) {

    casper.start("http://localhost:8080/site", function() {
        this.fill(searchForm, { query: goodQuery }, true);
    });

    casper.waitForSelector('#someSelectorOnNextPage', function() {
        test.assertTitle('Search Result', 'Search result title is ok');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also experience same issue. Suprisingly adding empty `then()` handler fixes that in `v1.1.0-beta3`. I don't think this is expected behavior though:

```
casper.test.begin('Search', function(test) {

  casper.start("http://localhost:8080/site", function() {
    this.fill(searchForm, { query: goodQuery }, true);
  });

  // Do nothing here, just call it as a placeholder
  // Here http://localhost:8080/site sends us to the next endpoint
  casper.then(function() {});

  // Now this is the final page we actually want to assert
  casper.then(function() {
    test.assertTitle('Search Result', 'Search result title is ok');
  });
}
```

EDIT:

Although question author says `casper.waitForUrl()` didn't work for them, it did work for me as an alternative solution.

What does look strange is that in verbose mode whatever returns a 301 status code along with `Location` Header is recognized as `HTTP 200` response by Casper.

EDIT 2:

Well obviously it doesn't happen every time, but what I noticed is that Casper sometimes doubles the previous response (that's why I thought it recognizes some specific HTTP codes as 200 mistakenly and that's why author's code functioned as if it stayed on same page after form submission) and sometimes not.

`waitForUrl()` fixes that obviously but there is still some underneath issue in Casper which scares me a bit and I hope I will find some time to report it with all the dumps to Casper issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Can't confirm if this could help, project is long gone (I don't have Windows to retest it). The empty `then()` is certainly not the intended way like you say. I suspect the outcome of `waitForUrl()` is somehow not reproducible in all cases. Glad it does the trick for you though. What you say about `http 301` is unsettling too. Worth noting: I didn't receive any support on the casper.js group; the problem was not even acknowledged. All of that will probably drive me away from casper on my next project.

Comment: Sure. Casper is very convenient in general, I'm sorry we have to fall into some traps with it and to run after project's API changes which made many tutorials and code samples outdated but hope they will fix these issues and avoid changing API that much in the future.